# My python class is giving an error at print

Tags: python, class

Here is my code

```
class Question:

    def __int__(self, q_text, q_answer):

        self.text = q_text

        self.answer = q_answer

new_q = Question("first", "False")

print(new_q.text)
```

I get this as error:

```
new_q = Question("first", "False")
TypeError: Question() takes no arguments
```

I was expecting it will print out first.

Comment: You are using `__int__` instead of `__init__` to initiate your class